# Orchid growing a second plant?

Tags: cuttings, orchids

About 3 weeks ago I purchased my first orchid on a whim, suspecting I'd end up killing him. But he's been growing happily, I've had 2 new flowers from him within that time! (I've recently learnt that I have green fingers :D) I haven't used anything other than water and Baby Bio to grow him.

A few days ago I noticed a new growth on him and I'm unsure what to do with it as I hadn't researched them much before my purchase.

I've attached a picture in hope of some advice, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your question and the good picture. Would you mind editing your question to be more precise on what you really want to know? If it just "how to handle" then I'd also suggest to remove the 'cuttings' tag, this tag is for indicating 'cuttings' which are used to produce new plants.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple: That's a new flower stalk growing out of an old one. [Phalenopsises](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalaenopsis) often re-flower, so do not cut the green stalks off after one "round" but leave them until dry. If you are really lucky it may even grow a "baby plant" ("[keiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/keiki)") on the flower stalk. (Some day, this isn't, it's clearly flower buds.)

The Phalenopsis / Moth orchids typically sold in garden centers etc. are hybrids breed for their eagerness to bloom and considered ideal for beginners in orchid care.

But always remember that in the wild these orchids grow on trees with a very limited supply of nutritients - some rotting leaves that got stuck in the fork of a branch, for example - so "feeding them well" will actually kill them. Always use a special fertilizer for orchids and follow the instructions. If you have been using regular fertilizer, I suggest a "fast" for your plant that should be about twice as long as you have been fertilizing to balance it back.